# Realm: Create new instances of User is removing stored lists of other User instances

Tags: swift, realm

In my User model I store some list like this:

```
public final class User: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String? = nil
    var addresses = List<Address>()
    var children = List<Child>()
    var godparents = List<User>()
}
```

I save the user with the id 1 in Realm, with some addresses and children, it's working great and it's persisted after the app is killed.

But when I want to create totally new users, for example user with ids 2 & 3, the user with id 1 will lost all list data (name will be still persisted, but all addresses or children are lost). What's wrong here ?

Here is the code where I want to add users 2 & 3 in godparents list of user 1:

```
do {
    try realm.write {
        // users contains user 2 & 3
        let users = self.users.map { (userData) -> User in                
            return realm.create(User.self, value: userData, update: true)
        }

        UserManager.currentUser?.godparents.removeAll()
        UserManager.currentUser?.godparents.append(contentsOf: users)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error) // no error is triggered at this point
}
```

After this code is executed, user 1 lost all data in addresses & children

Here is a code of currentUser method if needed (to get user id 1):

```
struct UserManager {
    static var currentUser: User? {
        get {
            guard let id = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "current_user_id") else {
                return nil
            }

            let user = realm?.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
            return user
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is user 1 included in that `self.users.map` call at all? Since `update` is equal to true, if user 1 is in there, it will get updated as well. And if the `addresses` and `children` properties are present, but empty, that will clear those pre-existing properties.

Comment: Hmmm, in fact you are right, users.count is about only these two users, but one of these users contains the user 1 in his sublist property (godparents). Everything is updated at the end, damn !

Comment: Hahaha aha! I thought so. Okay I'll write up a formal answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `realm.create()` with `update: true`, you need to be very careful what you pass to it. Realm doesn't treat present, but empty values as 'do not touch', it instead assumes you wanted to `nil` out that value.

Assuming `userData` is just a standard dictionary, you should only pass the values you want to change, and (ideally) omit any values that don't change.